# Math to crunch a list of values into their unique 3 digit selves. UNION by 3 digits

Tags: php, math, union

Looking for a way to unite in the UNION fashion a list like this.

```
87401
87441
87561
86421
57401
```

into an array or somthing like this, notice there is only one 874.

```
874
875
864
574
```

Here is what I came up with and it works, but I am looking for a way I don't have to iterate over the array 3->4 times

```
$l=array(87401,87402,87400,87801,73567,80031);
print_r($l);
function sub(&$item1, $key, $n=3)
{
    $item1 = substr($item1,0,$n);
}

array_walk($l,'sub',3);
print_r( array_unique($l));
//output is below
Array ( [0] => 874 [3] => 878 [4] => 735 [5] => 800 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
$nums = array(87401,87441,87561,86421,57401,'4.1007995605469E-5','3.6001205444336E-5');
$result = array();
foreach($nums as $n){
    $num = floor(substr($n,0,3));
    if(!in_array($num,$result)){
        $result[] = $num;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be less iterations, I will benchmark, thanks so much you are awesome. God Bless you

Comment: JesusIsLord
4.2200088500977E-5
Samuel Cook
3.6001205444336E-5

Comment: But what about mathmatically

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr=array(87401, 87441, 87561, 86421, 57401);

$callback = function($num) { return substr($num,0,3); };
$newarr = array_unique(array_map($callback, $arr));
```

Comment: @MayurBirari: `array_map()` traverses `$arr` and applies the `$callback` function to each array member. It returns an array.  `array_unique()` removes any duplicates and returns an array.